# Empty substring, what's wrong here?

Tags: php

Warning: substr_count() [function.substr-count]: Empty substring.

I get this message when calling the function browsertest. Here is the part of the function, it tells me that here is something wrong

```
if(substr_count($referer, $tld[$i]) > 0)
```

the function is displayed beneath. Thank you for your time and interest in my problem.

```
function testbrowser()
{
    //check for browser type
    $useragent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    //set safe browser types
    $browser[0] = "msie 6";
    $browser[1] = "msie 7";
    $browser[2] = "firefox";
    $browser[3] = "safari";

    $i = 0;
    $user_agent_ok = 0;
    while($i < 4)
    {
        if(strpos($useragent, $browser[$i]) > 0)
        {
            $user_agent_ok = 1;
            $i=4;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if ($user_agent_ok == 1)
    {
        //check referer
        $safe = 0;
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM safe_referers";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        //check for blank referer
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != ""  AND (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) == 0))
        {
            //strip down referer information to http://subdomain.domain.tld
            $tld[0] = ".com";
            $tld[1] = ".net";
            $tld[2] = ".org";
            $tld[3] = ".info";
            $tld[4] = ".co.uk";
            $tld[5] = ".co.in";
            $tld[6] = ".it";
            $tld[8] = ".gr";
            $tld[9] = ".no";
            $tld[10] = ".de";
            $tld[11] = ".ru";
            $tld[12] = ".pl";
            $tld[13] = ".dk";
            $tld[14] = ".pt";
            $tld[15] = ".ca";

            $i = 0;
            while($i < 16)
            {
                $referer = strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "http://");
                if(substr_count($referer, $tld[$i]) > 0)
                {
                    $referer = substr($referer, 0, strpos($referer, $tld[$i]));
                    $referer = $referer . $tld[$i];
                    $i=16;
                }
                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: please put your complete function

Comment: the rest of the function has nothing to do with the error itself. the substr_count causes sometimes the error

Comment: well the firs thing i would do is throw in a `var_dump($tld[$i])` for debugging... see what the value is youre actually dealing with...

Comment: A good debugging technique is to dump the variable that is giving problems. Try `var_dump()` function to see if you variable has a right value.

Comment: no need for var_dump here. but it's still good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot to set `$tld[7]` and have detailled warning disabled.

Rewrite the inner loop, like this:

```
$tlds = array('.com', '.net', '.org', '.info', '.co.uk', '.co.in', '.it', '.gr',
              '.no', '.de', '.ru', '.pl', '.dk', '.pt', '.ca');

foreach ($tlds as $tld) {
   $referer = strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "http://");
   $p = strpos($referer, $tld);
   if ($p !== false) {
       $referer = substr($referer, 0, $p) . $tld;
   }
}
```

Comment: oops! thanks for this, I corrected it and will try again, nevertheless I want to have warining disabled but manage it somehow that no warning appears when the ref is blank

Comment: thank you :) I worked out, I have overlooked the 7th one. Also I implemented your idea and it works out as desired! I appreciate your time and interest for my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$tld[7] is missing. When looping through them you will get an empty substring

Now sometimes it will match before you reach $i == 7. Then the error will not occur.

You could use

```
$tld = array_values($tld);
while ($i < count($tld)) {
```

or instead of while use

```
foreach ($tld as $v) {
```

The loop could look like this

```
$tld = array(".com",".net",".org",".info",".co.uk",".co.in",".it",".gr",".no",".de",".ru",".pl",".dk",".pt",".ca");

foreach ($tld as $v)
{
    $referer = strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "http://");
    if(strstr($referer, $v))
    {
        $referer = substr($referer, 0, strpos($referer, $v));
        $referer = $referer . $v;
        break;
    }
}
```

But this is how I would write it

```
$tld = array(".com",".net",".org",".info",".co.uk",".co.in",".it",".gr",".no",".de",".ru",".pl",".dk",".pt",".ca");
foreach ($tld as $v)
{
    if (preg_match('#\\'.$v.'/#',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $referer = preg_replace('#(^http(s*)://[^/]*).*#','\1',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. Need to add a check, something like !is_null() or !empty().

Comment: +1 And that's why you declare arrays using `array('.com', '.net', ...)` and iterate them using `foreach`. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is empty if you are not visiting the page by clicking on a link, it can also be empty if the client (browser) doesn't send it in the first place, [see the documentation for `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Thank you Kristoffer! I thought this could be a problem because it does not show up every time. How can I manage to not get the error message in the front end when the ref is blank? Thank you in advance

Comment: `substr_count()` doesn't care if the `$haystack` (first param) is empty, only if the `$needle` (second param) is.

Comment: You got me there... hardly ever use substr_count so I got the ordering wrong... Note to self: Read the documentation you link to

Comment: You still beat me. I tested both of them to be sure, but didn't read far enough into OPs question and ended up looking at the wrong `substr_count` call.